# GTK#: Tree View with Filter AND Sorting

Tags: mono, monodevelop, gtk#

I have a Tree View object which can be filtered via the `TreeModelFilter`.
As soon as I set the filter with `tree.Model = filter;`,
the sorting no longer works.

Is there a way of having the filter working AND be able to sort by clicking on the column headers?

In summary I want a `filterable, searchable, sortable, multi-selection Tree View Control` in order to view results from the data base.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be, after reading the Gtk+ documentation, that a tree view could be [filtered](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3AGtk.TreeModelFilter) and [sortable](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3AGtk.TreeModelSort) at the same time.

But you won't be able to use any of those classes. My bet is that you will have to create your own model implementing the interfaces for [sorting](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3AGtk.TreeSortableImplementor) and providing filtering.

Gtk# is very powerful. Unfortunately, it is very complex at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

To sort a filterable model you need to wrap your filtered_model with a Gtk.TreeModelSort.

```
    sorted_model = Gtk.TreeModelSort(model=self.filter)
```

If you don't want to use the default sort method, you can set a custom sort function.

```
    sorted_model.set_sort_func(0, self.sort_tree, None)
```

Later you can set the treeview to use this sort model.

```
    self.tree_view = Gtk.TreeView(model=sorted_model)
```